# What should go in <anything-here> part of the redirect URI while registering for oAuth client for chrome identity API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon

I want to set up oAuth for a **NON-google account** using Chrome Identity API in my extension. I need to register my extension to get a oAuth client Id for which I need a redirected URI of the form `https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/<anything-here>`. I am not sure what should go in the `<anything-here>` part of the redirected URI. The extension needs to get authentication from several websites which use their own SSO.

Comment: Anything that is still a valid URI, like `https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/auth` or `https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/areallyunnecessarilylongauthredirecturi` :)

Comment: I still don't get it :( Does the ```<anything-here>``` part even matter? And if it does, shouldn't there be a specific thing that should go there? Either way, if I just put ```https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/auth``` it is going to work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the `/<anything-here>` part of the url doesn't even need to be there for oAuth to resolve. It can be left blank and the oAuth will still be fine.

My best guess about its usage is that, it can be used to add further information about where the request is coming from.

`https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/SSOMethod1`

`https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/authfromgoogleaccount`

`https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/id=1234556`

We can now choose to handle them differently if we want to.